# Converting structs from C to C++ (POD)

Tags: c++, c

I have a set of `structs` which come from some C code I'm converting to C++, they should be POD types according to what I understood. Here are some examples:

```
struct Data {
  u16 type : 12;
  u8 variant : 3;
  bool isTop : 1;
};

struct DData {
  u16 type : 12;
  u8 variant : 3;
  u8 layer : 1;
};

struct TData {
  struct Data data1, data2;
  struct DData ddata[MAX];
  u16 x;
  u8 y;
  u8 s : 4;
  u8 l : 4;
  u8 wl : 3;
  u8 wr : 3;
  u8 lt : 2;
};
```

I have many methods which up to now had pointer to these structs as parameters and I was planning to move them directly inside the struct declarations to save a lot of typing, eg.

```
struct Data {
  u16 type : 12;
  u8 variant : 3;
  bool isTop : 1;

  inline bool hasFlag(u64 flag) { return Types::specs[type].flags & flag; }
 };
```

I was wondering if every method I can add in this way will be safe for this `struct`, these structures are serialized over the network and into binary files so I need to be sure that this can't potentially break anything. If I'm right they should remain POD types so no particular problems or overhead should appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should remain a POD.

You can be sure by using the `std::is_pod` trait:

```
std::is_pod<Data>::value;
```

will be `true` if `Data` is a POD, false otherwise.

Anyway, I wouldn't bother moving the functions into the struct body. You're not really gaining anything besides a different calling syntax.

Comment: Curiously none of the struct is reported as POD by the `is_pod` trait. I wonder why, maybe the packing of field with bitfields has something to do? It seems strange though.

Comment: @Jack It worked on my gcc: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0d31687b000ddca688e12ad6fd0eea44 Not sure about the bitfields though.

Comment: I mean that they are no reported as POD even with no method declared inside them, I always supposed they were since they're just structs.